# How to play .mp3 instead of .wav?

Tags: java, audio

How do I get and  use mp3s instead of .wav? This works fine with wav files but gets an error with mp3.

```
  private String audioFile = "/audio/menu_screen.wav";
 public void getSound() {
    BufferedInputStream inaudio = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(audioFile)); 


    clip = null;
    try {

        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inaudio));

    } catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}

public void playSound(int x) {
  if(clip != null){
  clip.stop();
  }
```

The error is..

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1119)
at frogger.Board.getSound(Board.java:181)
at frogger.Board.muted(Board.java:235)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Some formats just aren't supported by java.
you could try transcoding it or using a native library such as LWGJL or a java library that supports mp3.
because afaik javax.sound doesn't support mp3

Comment: @MichaelHaywood was looking forward to a bit more detail than that.

Comment: Take a look at [JLayer/JavaZoom](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying using the `Media` and `Media Player` Classes this:-

```
String s= "abc.mp3";
Media m= new Media(s);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(m);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .ogg instead of wav as that's what the Android docs recommend.

Also, SoundPool might be a good way to play clips in your apps - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html